# How can I improve window/session/instance/tab/file management and organization in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, file-organization

I love notepad++ and I use it every day for almost everything.

I am now coming up on 1,000 tabs open. Most of these tabs are like `new 459`, `new 782`, etc.

I find what I like to do is safe everything I type into a new file. But I can't be bothered to save the file, now it take 2-3 minutes for notepad++ to open so I just leave it open always now. No problem for me.

You see, I have almost 1,000 "`new xxx`" files which are files I have **not saved** but I rely on notepad++'s autosave feature.

[image]

Before the autosave, I never was able to save files because making a new file and saving it was too much of a hassle so when i restarted my pc i lost everything. Needless to say, autosave has really been awesome for me!

Now that it can autosave now I can save everything without disrupting my workflow. Doing some random code? Copy into notepad++. Wrote something on forum? copy into notepad++. Doing some accounting? New tab, paste work in the text file.

It is a hassle for me to individually save all these files so I love to just open a new tab, paste, and continue with my work.

I also find that I now usually have two windows - the left and right - in the same instance.

Usually what goes in my left window is a user details page which contains a bunch of vital information I access regularly. But here is an example screenshot of the left-right window process:

[image]

Now I find myself doing something even more advanced. I will open up a new instance in notepad++ to have a clean window to work from to organize a new project. I do this by going to `Run > Open in another instance`. It opens a new instance without messing with my original instance.

[image]

There are a couple downsides to this.

1. If I have to restart my pc, I have to close all instances to make sure that I didn't lose anything I pasted in there instead of the main window.
2. I lose any work done on files in there on close so I have top manually copy each one into the original instance.. I would love to have an instance where I have maybe 300 files open from a folder where I can easily search all, but in its separate instance so I just toggle over there.
3. Sometimes I get mixed up and paste whatever I am doing in the wrong instance (instead of the original)
4. Sometimes I have like 7 instances open and it gets confusing to find it
5. Sometimes I get mixed up and paste whatever I am doing in the wrong instance (instead of the original)
6. Sometimes it's hard to find the original instance with many open

Reason I do this like 300 files, which in some new instances is as many as thousands of files, is if I am editing a website for example. Sometimes instead of trying to search for text I will open whole folders of a website and just do a "find all". Some people may not like this, but it works for me. (Update: I was looking around and saw many other people do this too!)

But here is another downside of having my primary window with almost 1000 "new" files open: It isn't organized at all. I find stuff by doing a "Find All in All Opened Documents" function. Which works but is not efficient. But it works.

[image]

Please note that I just upgraded to the newest version and I saw the "Workspace Sorting" feature. That does NOT work for me, and I have disabled it! Thank goodness I did not upgrade notepadd++ for a few versions, because the developer added the option to [disable that feature in version 7.0](http://techdows.com/2016/09/notepad-7-disable-folder-as-workspace-feature.html#comment-125090).

Something I would really love, is to have something which can manage multiple sessions and autosave an unlimited number of files with super easy drag and drop sorting without having to save the files and make a filename.

Is there anything that can improve my workflow and help me organize thousands of files as well as have new sessions with the fully opened thousands of files in a particular session (instance)?

Basically I don't want to complicate my current workflow with having to do more things (even one or two clicks is too much of a hassle when I do as many things at once as I do), but I would like to be more organized and have a better way of managing new sessions (instances).

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ will not work this way because you have unsaved files.

When you go to file->Save all, you can save all documents. Find a folder for your temp files, and hold enter to save all files into that folder.

Now you can use menu file->Save session to store that session, and continue to it later.

Either by loading a different session, or by choosing close all, you can stop working with the files.

Do note, by default, notepad++ will start counting from 1 and up when creating a new file. If you save all files, and you close and open a session, and you press new, it will start counting from 1 again, meaning that if you save, it will ask you to override your file.

Unsaved new files will not be stored in sessions. Unsaved existing files will. A session only stores the path to the file.

Comment: i would have to click 1,000 times and as i said, saving them individually as filenames is not a viable option for me as it disrupts my work flow. Remember i said that before the autosave i just didn't even bother to save the files at all because it was more of a hassle than anything to save individual files. if I have to save by filenames it would result in me not using the feature. which is why i do it like i do now.

Comment: Which is why I started with: "Notepad++ will not work this way because you have unsaved files" Aka: what you want cannot be done, so the only way to work with this, is to save files. You can save all 1000+ of them in less than 5 minutes by holding enter. They all will have the new####.txt but they will be saved.

Comment: I'm looking for someone to tell me what I can do, not what I can't. Just saying "you can't do that" doesn't progress me any further, does it? If you could offer an alternative since what you think I am asking you don't think is possible, although it could be interpreted in a different way, the important thing is improving work flow without adding additional actions to work flow.

Comment: My answer gives you a way to do it, but it requires you to save a file. This is called wishful thinking. Just because you want something to be possible doesn't mean it actually is possible.

Comment: No, your answer does not give a way to do it without adding additional actions to workflow or disrupting my workflow. Your answer does the opposite.